# Remember me option for outlook addin

Tags: c#

How can i create "Remember me" option for outlook addin.(In textBox)
I don't want to connnect it to the database.
I just want to save the user credentials on his/her computer when he/s login to the outlook addin. 
This addin will connect the user to the site by using web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user/app specific registry access you can use the following functions:

```
Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue
```

and

```
Application.UserAppDataRegistry.GetValue
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `CustomDocumentProperties` available on the active project to store and retrieve user properties.

```
DocumentProperties docProps = ( DocumentProperties )this.Application.ActiveProject.CustomDocumentProperties;
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty projNameProp = docProps.Add( builtinPropertyName, false, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, value, missing );
projNameProp.Value = value;
```

Comment: CustomDocumentProperties are scoped to documents, OP needs something scoped to the entire Outlook app.